# How to create scrollable table in a fixed height box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed height table that becomes scrollable upon a certain number of rows being appended to it. I have created a flexbox container with a box that contains the table and I intend to write Javascript to make it infinitely scrollable.

The issue I am facing is when the table becomes a height that extends beyond the bounds of the box, and it does not become scrollable after reaching the margin of that box.

I would like the table to stay within the box, and after the nth number of table rows appended to it, it becomes scrollable within the box.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>#</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\css\core.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>TIME</th>
                                <th>TICKER</th>
                                <th>CALL/PUT</th>
                                <th>EXPIRY</th>
                                <th>STRIKE</th>
                                <th>SPOT</th>
                                <th>PRICE</th>
                                <th>SIZE</th>
                                <th>PREMIUM</th>
                                <th>OI</th>
                                <th>IV</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass&display=swap);
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color: #060c17;
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: #0c1427;
    border: 2px solid #172340;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.row {
display: flex;
}

.column {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    height: 690px;
}

.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-height: 0;
}

thead {
    color: #7886a1;
}

tbody {
    color: white;
}

.table thead tbody {
    width: 950px;
}

.table thead th {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
    padding: 25px;
}

.table tbody td {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
    padding: 25px;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #060c17;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow: auto;` to `.box`:

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass&display=swap);
body {
  background-color: #060c17;
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #0c1427;
  border: 2px solid #172340;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  height: 690px;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-height: 0;
}

thead {
  color: #7886a1;
}

tbody {
  color: white;
}

.table thead tbody {
  width: 950px;
}

.table thead th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
  padding: 25px;
}

.table tbody td {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
  padding: 25px;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #060c17;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>TICKER</th>
                <th>CALL/PUT</th>
                <th>EXPIRY</th>
                <th>STRIKE</th>
                <th>SPOT</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>SIZE</th>
                <th>PREMIUM</th>
                <th>OI</th>
                <th>IV</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>00:12:34</td>
                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                <td>4/28</td>
                <td>$7800</td>
                <td>$7219</td>
                <td>₿0.031</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>₿62</td>
                <td>60.9%</td>
                <td>1120</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass&display=swap);
body {
    background-color: #060c17;
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: #0c1427;
    border: 2px solid #172340;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    height: 690px;
}

.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-height: 0;
}

thead {
    color: #7886a1;
}

tbody {
    color: white;
}

.table thead tbody {
    width: 950px;
}

.table thead th {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
    padding: 25px;
}

.table tbody td {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262f43;
    padding: 25px;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #060c17;
}
.column {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>#</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\css\core.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>TIME</th>
                                <th>TICKER</th>
                                <th>CALL/PUT</th>
                                <th>EXPIRY</th>
                                <th>STRIKE</th>
                                <th>SPOT</th>
                                <th>PRICE</th>
                                <th>SIZE</th>
                                <th>PREMIUM</th>
                                <th>OI</th>
                                <th>IV</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>00:12:34</td>
                                <td style="color: orange;">BTC</td>
                                <td style="color:#ff3366;">PUT</td>
                                <td>4/28</td>
                                <td>$7800</td>
                                <td>$7219</td>
                                <td>₿0.031</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>₿62</td>
                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                <td>1120</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```